# Adding a new page to a website

Tags: hyperlink, new-operator

sorry if this question seems a bit open ended, but I'm often wanting to add new pages to my website. As my website grows, this means I'm having go back and add a link to the new page on *all* of my previous pages, which is becoming increasingly time consuming. Is there any way around this? An automatic method? Obviously in an ideal world you'd get the template page correct first, but this doesn't seem to allow for easy expansion. How do the big sites cope? Thanks.

Comment: What framework/language are you using?

Comment: So far I've just been using HTML, but what Walkerneo has suggested seems like just the thing I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You user server-side includes.

In PHP there are `include()` and `require()`

`include('filename.php')` will add the contents of 'filename.php' to the page it was included on. Require does the same thing, but the script stops if it can't locate or use the file.

Instead of doing:

```
<div id="navbar" >
    <ul>
        <li>Menu</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Put it in a file called "navbar.html" and just do:

```
<?PHP include('navbar.html'); ?>
```

In your include file you could have:

```
<div id="navbar" >
    <ul>
        <li id="1" class="<?PHP echo $m1class ?>">Menu</li>
        <li id="2" class="<?PHP echo $m2class ?>">item</li>
        <li id="3" class="<?PHP echo $m3class ?>">item</li>
        <li id="4" class="<?PHP echo $m4class ?>">item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And then in the PHP file:

```
<?PHP
    $m1class=$m2class=$m4class="notCurrent";
    $m3class="current";
    include('navbar.php');
?>
```

It would be the same as doing:

```
<?PHP
        $m1class=$m2class=$m4class="notCurrent";
        $m3class="current";
        include('navbar.php');
?>
<div id="navbar" >
        <ul>
            <li id="1" class="<?PHP echo $m1class ?>">Menu</li>
            <li id="2" class="<?PHP echo $m2class ?>">item</li>
            <li id="3" class="<?PHP echo $m3class ?>">item</li>
            <li id="4" class="<?PHP echo $m4class ?>">item</li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

...except that you can change the include file so that it changes every page. The output of either would be:

```
<div id="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li id="1" class="notCurrent">Menu</li>
            <li id="2" class="notCurrent">item</li>
            <li id="3" class="current">item</li>
            <li id="4" class="notCurrent">item</li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Goodluck!

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be exactly the kind of thing I need. Just one issue; I'd like a particular item in the menu to have a class of "current" when that page is viewed. Is this just a simple case of putting a bit of javascript on the page to add the class?

Comment: When you include a file, it's as if everything in the file is in the place you included it. I'll update the post.

Comment: Thank you, this is very useful. Just one thing, what is the purpose of the include('test') statement? What is 'test'?

Comment: Dang, sorry. I probably confused the crap out of you there. I named by navbar page test and uploaded it to my server to verify that was I was saying was correct. I'll change it for you. Sorry about any confusion.